# Swift generics compiler error: Cannot convert value of type

Tags: json, swift, generics, closures, jsondecoder

I'm trying to reuse code here, but the compiler won't have it. MyModel implements Decodable.

```
func removeApplicationRequestOperation(request: Request, completion: @escaping (Result<MyModel, Error>) -> Void) -> RequestOperation {
    return newRequestOperation(for: request, modelType: MyModel.self, completion: completion) // <-- Won't compile!
}


private func newRequestOperation<T: Decodable>(for request: Request?, modelType: T.Type, completion: @escaping (Result<T.Type, Error>) -> Void) -> RequestOperation {
        return requestOperation(request: request) { operation in
            do {
                guard let response = operation.response, response.successful,
                      let rawData = response.rawData,
                      let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(modelType, from: rawData) as? T.Type else {
                        completion(.failure(.parsingError))
                        return
                }
                completion(.success(model))
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(.parsingError))
            }
        }
    }
```

Error: `Cannot convert value of type '(Result<MyModel, Error>) -> Void' to expected argument type '(Result<_.Type, Error>) -> Void'`

Comment: Change completion:  `(Result<T.Type, Error>)` to completion: `(Result<T, Error>)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Doing that moves the error to success completion with the message: `Member 'success' in 'Result<_, Error>' produces result of type 'Result<Success, Failure>', but context expects 'Result<_, Error>'`

Comment: Why do you need to return `RequestOperation` ? Just use a completion handler. Remove  `-> RequestOperation`from both method signatures. And post your `requestOperation` method.

Comment: pass in Result only your model Result<MyModel>

Comment: @LeoDabus We add the operation to a queue manually while performing other stuff. I have to live with it. Why can't I put the model in a success case?